# ActiveMQ: Store JMS message permanently after consumption

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have setup `ActiveMQ` and able to produce and consume `MapMessage`. Message gets stored in `ACTIVEMQ_MSGS` table under Oracle until it is getting consumed. After consumption record from database gets deleted.

Writing trigger and manually pushing data in to another table is one option. But I just want to check with you whether is there any property I can set with which this can be accomplished.

My configuration from `activemq.xml` looks like this:

```
    <bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE"/>
          <property name="username" value="USERNAME"/>
          <property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
          <property name="maxActive" value="200"/>
          <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>


    <persistenceAdapter>
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#oracle-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

My Java code looks like:

```
// Getting JMS connection from the server and starting it
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(Constants.ACTIVEMQ_URL);
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Destination represents 'NIKHIL.QUEUE' on the JMS server.
Destination destination = session.createQueue("NIKHIL.QUEUE");

// MessageProducer is used for sending messages (as opposed to MessageConsumer which is used for receiving them)
producer = session.createProducer(destination);

//Message creation goes here...
```

Comment: Not sure why StackOverFlow hides person name who gave -1. At least they should mandate person to write a comment about it which anonymously can be shared with me. Please let me know what is wrong in my question. Thank you! :-)

Comment: I think they probably did so because you aren't really asking a real question.  What are you hoping to achieve?  What have you tried?  What didn't work? etc etc.

Comment: Tim, I think what I have tried, what approach I thought of and what I want to achieve is clearly shared in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in the question the only answer that fits is, No.  There is no property to make the Messages magically go to some other table in your DB.  The broker is working as designed, when messages are consumed they are removed.  If you want some sort of mirroring you could try creating a composite destination such that messages arriving in one Queue are dispatched to two separate Queues and you consume from one and preserve the other but then you'd need to manage that in some way.

Comment: I have observed in case of topics that if the message is persistent and it's consumed by consumers(and there is no offline durable consumer) the entry still persists in `activemq_msgs`. Isn't this entry supposed to be removed? or I am understanding something wrong

Comment: Okay  I got it entires from the database are deleted by a scheduler, it's not happening instantly as I was expecting. If you enable debug in log u can see ```DEBUG | Executing SQL: DELETE FROM ACTIVEMQ_MSGS WHERE (PRIORITY=? AND ID <=      ( SELECT min(ACTIVEMQ_ACKS.LAST_ACKED_ID)       FROM ACTIVEMQ_ACKS WHERE ACTIVEMQ_ACKS.CONTAINER=ACTIVEMQ_MSGS.CONTAINER        AND ACTIVEMQ_ACKS.PRIORITY=?)   ) | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter | Persistence Adaptor Task-1```